# Selenium Chromedriver opening a blank page

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

When I open this URL with webdriver in selenium, I get a blank page with a  429 request. I haven't sent too many request as I only do one and it doesn't work. I've tried multiple solutions but can't manage to do it. Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
# to supress the error messages/logs
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_argument("disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r"C:\\Users\\pople\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.bluenile.com/diamond-search')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access that page with `undetected_chromedriver`

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
browser = uc.Chrome()

url = 'https://www.bluenile.com/diamond-search'


browser.get(url)
```

You can install the package with `pip install undetected-chromedriver`. Make sure your chrome browser is up to date, and your chromedriver is compatible with it.